# For one linked image per post, override that link with a permalink when on the main page

Tags: customization, permalinks

Is there an existing plugin that allows a person to, in a post, put a link on an image, but when the post is shown as part of the main-page list, have that image link to the post's permalink instead.

If not, can you point me in the right direction to custom code this myself? (What files to edit, what WP functions already exist that might help me...)
I have a decent grasp of functional/procedural PHP, but have only the slightest experience editing WP code.

I am using WordPress 3.9 and the theme "Twenty Ten"

Feel free to re-tag this question. I am not familiar enough with WP or WP.SE to know what tags are best.

Comment: Depends on where you're posts are showing up, could be index.php or some kind of archive.php - are these posts you're referring to "Posts" or are they "Pages"? or something different?

Comment: They are posts. The edit link looks like this: `wp-admin/post.php?post=1531&action=edit` On this site "Pages" is empty. The place where I want the images to link to the permalinks is the main page of the site.

Comment: Just remember, asking for plugin/product recommendations are off topic.

Comment: @PieterGoosen, I saw that when I looked for a good tag, but thought that "If not, can you point me in the right direction to custom code this myself?" would offset that well enough. I ended up doing just that, and have answered my own question.

Comment: @PieterGoosen The edit you did on my title changes the meaning of it. I'm new enough here that I **REALLY** don't want to get into an edit war, so I ask you to please reconsider your edit.

Comment: OK, rolled back my changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to work in the twentyten theme folder, the file "loop.php"

Around line 145 I did this:

```
<?php $content = get_the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) );
  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/6366390/1195835
  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/11886237/1195835
  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/15469353/1195835
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($content);
  $finder = new DomXPath($doc);
  $classname = "post-main-image";
  $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");      
  foreach($nodes as $node){
   $node->setAttribute('href',get_the_permalink());
  }
  echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```

Then in the edit post screen, I simply type "post-main-image" in the "Link CSS Class" form field and update. I would expect something similar to work in other themes as well.